# Printing in bluetooth thermal printer where my bottom text becomes small

Tags: android, printing, itext, thermal-printer, bluetooth-printing

I am trying to print a receipt from a Bluetooth thermal printer with a receipt size of

> •Paper Width: 57 +/- 0.5mm
> •Print Width: 48 +/- 0.5mm

Bluetooth thermal printer model (might help for more specification)

> PT-210 Portable Wireless Bluetooth Thermal Printer Handheld 58mm
> Receipt

Here is my current code, I am using **iTextPDF package**

```
 public void ForInventoryPDF() {
     //   Rectangle pagesize = new Rectangle(288, 700);
   
        Document document = new Document();
     //  Document document = new Document(pagesize);
     //** ^^ I tried to do this, but when i did. i can only show atleast 10 items in a right font size while the other 10 item shows in a very small font size.


        try {
            PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(SALESFILE));
        } catch (DocumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

// Open to write
        document.open();
       // document.setPageSize(PageSize.A8);

        document.addCreationDate();
        document.addAuthor("lafayet order");
        document.addCreator("Kiko lawrence");


        LineSeparator lineSeparator = new LineSeparator();
        lineSeparator.setLineColor(new BaseColor(0, 0, 0, 68));

        BaseFont urName = null;
        try {
            urName = BaseFont.createFont("/res/font/brandon_medium.otf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
        } catch (DocumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Font mOrderDetailsTitleFont = new Font(urName, 30.0f, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK);
        Font dateFont = new Font(urName, 14.0f, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK);

        // Creating Chunk
        Chunk mOrderDetailsTitleChunk = new Chunk("SALE SUMMARY - ANTIPOLO  ", mOrderDetailsTitleFont);
        Chunk dateChunk = new Chunk("Date : " + getDateTime() + "\n\n", dateFont);


        Paragraph mOrderDetailsTitleParagraph = new Paragraph(mOrderDetailsTitleChunk);
        mOrderDetailsTitleParagraph.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);

        Paragraph date = new Paragraph(dateChunk);
        date.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        date.setSpacingBefore(5);

        Paragraph address = new Paragraph("Version 1.2");
        address.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);

        try {
            document.add(mOrderDetailsTitleParagraph);
            document.add(address);
            document.add(date);
            document.add(lineSeparator);
            PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(3);
            table.setWidthPercentage(100);
            table.addCell(getCell("Item Name", PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER));
            table.addCell(getCell("Quantity", PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
            table.addCell(getCell("Price", PdfPCell.ALIGN_RIGHT));
            document.add(table);
            document.add(new Paragraph("\n"));
        } catch (DocumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //START OF ORDER DETAILS
        if (inventoryModels != null && !inventoryModels.isEmpty()) {
            //**deleted unnecessary codes,
            //codes here are just for my items that i'm showing in the receipt.
        }

  
        document.close();
        openPdf(SALESFILE);

    }
```

I had to try different approach so far :

```
   //   Rectangle pagesize = new Rectangle(288, 700);
      //  Document document = new Document(pagesize);
        //** ^^ I tried to do this, but when i did. i can only show atleast 10 items in a right font size while the other 10 item shows in a very small font size.
```

When the item size exceeds more than 10 items, all of my bottom text becomes very small.
I'm trying to make a POS with receipt printing but it seems like do i need to buy a different printer?
or is there any other way around to fix this?

Thank you